# converting XMLGregorianCalendar object in String format to XMLGregorianCalendar object again

Tags: java.util.date, java.util.calendar

I have converted an `XMLGregorianCalendar` object to String using `toString()` method. So in a String variable I have `"2014-09-02T10:55:58.000+05:30"` . Now I want to load this value to an `XMLGregorianCalendar` object again.

```
   GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        XMLGregorianCalendar xgcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
        System.out.println(xgcal);
        String strDate = xgcal.toString();
        System.out.println("In String format "+strDate);
```

I want to store this string value to a variable of type XMLGregorianCalendar . I used thsi `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");` but cant understand what to do next.Hope I clearly mentioned my problem. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can use:

```
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(String lexicalRepresentation)
```

I had a problem similar to the problem the OP describes. I got a XMLGregorianCalendar and had to store it in a String representation. For this purpose I used the .toString() method from XMLGregorianCalendar. 
Later there was the need to read the stored date and return it as a XMLGregorianCalendar encapsulated in an SOAP-Message.

This example creates a new XMLGregorianCalendar (supposed the stored String is read to *hereIsMyString*):

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = null;
try {
   xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(hereIsMyString);
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, yes I'll edit my original post an explain what the code is meant to do.